# boolean expression by using commands with "if-then-else"

Tags: bash

We know that it is possible to do `if command ; then something ; fi`, where the status returned from `command` is interpreted as boolean (0==true). We also know that is ok doing `if [[ $a > $b || $c == yes ]] ; then something; fi`.

But I'm curious because we are not allowed to combine commands like Boolean expressions using "if", as in `if cmd1 || cmd2; then ; something; fi`. Or can we?

There is other ways of doing this without "if" or even with nested if. However, I'm interested on using `if` :-).

Appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 3):

That is correct. The condition to an `if` statement is defined to be a list, which very roughly speaking is either a single pipeline, *or* two lists joined by `&&` or `||`. These are not Boolean operators, although there is a resemblance.  `a && b` runs `a`, then runs `b` *if* `a` succeeds. `a || b` runs `a`, then runs `b` *if* `a` fails.

Compare

```
if [[ $a > $b || $c == yes ]]; then   # conditional operators
if [[ $a > $b ]] || [[ $c == yes ]]; then   # shell operators
```

Given that `[[ ... ]]` is a built-in command, there is very little difference between the two. However, the *shell* operators have equal precedence, while the *conditional* operator `&&` has higher precedence than conditional `||`. That is

```
if a || b && c; then # same as (a || b) && c
if [[ a || b && c ]]; then # same as a || (b && c)
```

Answer (score 0):

I`ll just leave this here.

```
check_and() {
    if grep -q A <<<"$1" && grep -q C <<<"$1"; then
        echo YES
    else
        echo NO
    fi
}

check_or() {
    if grep -q A <<<"$1" || grep -q C <<<"$1"; then
        echo YES
    else
        echo NO
    fi
}

check_and ABC # YES
check_and ABD # NO
check_and ZBC # NO
check_and ZBD # NO

check_or ABC # YES
check_or ABD # YES
check_or ZBC # YES
check_or ZBD # NO
```